# How does Grails merge the config.groovy with the static web.xml file?

Tags: grails, web.xml, grails-2.0

Grails allows you to generate a static **web.xml** file with:

```
 grails install-templates
```

When you edit the generated web.xml file and add change config.groovy what does Grails at compile time do? How are these files merged to the final web.xml file, since you can specify web.xml related configurations in config.groovy?

Answer (score 0):

Grails have a package phase that will do the work needed to create the final `web.xml` file. If I'm not mistaken this is done by `GrailsProjectPackager#generateWebXml(GrailsPluginManager pluginManager)`.

This process will also look at your installed plugins, that can have customizations to be applied in the file, though the `doWithWebDescriptor` closure. You can [check it on Github](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-core/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/project/packaging/GrailsProjectPackager.groovy).

Comment: When I change some variable in config.groovy and in my static web.xml which value will be taken by Grails?